# Can I ask about a programming trend or culture on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, scope, asking-questions, site-recommendation

I have a question I'd like to air:  *Will the Python culture of 'find a library for it' kill the art of coding?*
I don't want to put it up on Stack Overflow if it's not right for the site. Is it a bad fit? Is there somewhere else that might work?

Comment: Will not reinventing the wheel stop people from driving?

Comment: No don't post that question to SO, it's definitely off-topic, because it's not a programming question, and is opinion-based.

Comment: I read [your comment explaining the trigger for this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307329/can-i-ask-about-a-programming-trend-or-culture-on-stack-overflow#comment254041_307331).  Although it's not a good fit for a question, *would it be appropriate to pose that question in a chat room?*

Comment: There are chat rooms here?  That would indeed seem like a good idea.  I need to go exploring ... :)

Comment: this question has been posted in [Python SO chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/26081199#26081199)

Comment: Has it? CABBAGE ROOM 6!!!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your question sounds like it is wildly off-topic for Stack Overflow, for two reasons:

- It doesn't fit our [on-topic subjects](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); you don't have a practical programming question, you have a question about *culture*.
- The question is entirely open-ended; it asks for *opinions*, rather than factual information. This definitely falls foul of the guidelines in our [*Don't ask* help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Stack Overflow is here to help you with *specific, practical programming problems*, where you want someone to explain why your code isn't working, or how to configure your text editor. Your question doesn't sound like one.

There is no site in the Stack Exchange network where this question would be on-topic; open-ended discussions like that just don't fit the Question-and-Answers model the network is built on.

Comment: I suspected as much.   I notice even this question here is getting down-votes.   I also note that everyone is answering the first part, confirming its not for SO, but no one is suggesting the correct part of SE.  Oh well.

Comment: @RFlack: that's because there is no SE site where the subject would fit. Such discussions are not a fit for the Question-and-Answers model.

Comment: @RFlack voting on meta is a bit different than on SO. For starters you don't loose rep and in many cases downvotes are used to indicate disagreement. My best guess is that the downvoters simply feel such a question is off-topic for pretty much every site in the SE network.

Comment: @ ivarni - phew!  (though it would have been helpful to just say that upfront in an answser!   Matrijn did get to it a comment on my comment.
....  My query got triggered by a Python question about partial sums of a sequence, which can be got by a simple Python list comprehension; but the main solution was to import a library.   Anyway ...

Comment: @RFlack didn't downvote, but I'd say a probable reason for them is apparent lack of research of what's on-topic for SO (whether that's true or not).

Comment: @ cupcake fwiw .. i have done a lot of research on eligibility etc over the last cpl of years, admitedly not today.   my question was probably badly worded (i didnt put as much thought into it as I would on SO proper; it would have been better phrased:  "Is there a SE site suitable for a question about programming culture* given that its off topic for SO"  (not sure culture is the right word actually.

Comment: @RFlack when you mention someone in a comment, don't leave a space between `@ username`, otherwise they won't get pinged.

Comment: @Cupcake ... oops didnt know how that worked.  Many thanks!

Comment: @RFlack: You seem to have misunderstood my answer; I gave a piece of Python code *based on the documentation for a standard Python 3 library*. It doesn't actually require any imports. What I did in my answer was to credit the authors of the solution by pointing to where I got the code from.

Comment: @Martijn sorry about that i was reading too fast.

Answer (score 4):

I see value in questions like this one. However, they clearly are not welcome on the stack exchange network.

Why not ask this question on Quora? It's an extremely active Q&A site and has a much different culture towards questions involving some level of ambiguity or personal opinion.

Answer (score -5):

Quora  would be better.

Here is a list of stacks:

https://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#

Maybe when python becomes popular enough, it too will one day get a stack ;)

Comment: It has nothing to do with popularity; there are several sites on which various subsets of Python questions are perfectly welcome, including most notably SO itself. Unfortunately, whether Python or Ruby, C++ or Haskell, the question in ... question ... is utterly unsuitable for Stack Exchange's model of concise authoritative answers.

Answer (score -9):

Wouldn't this be a good fit for [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: While Programmers accepts some kinds of subjective questions, [they have to be *answerable* subjective questions](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). I don't see how this question could lead to anything but open-ended, purely opinion-based discussion.

Comment: this question is a _very_ poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6742/31260) Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: ... **[Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl)**

Comment: It can be a valid question for Programmers.SE, if the question is worded properly, depending on OP's actual underlying question. Something like _"How to retain creativity in prorgamming when there's a library for almost every problem?"_, to which answers like _"You can reinvent the wheel for educational purposes"_ is very useful. However, that [question has already been asked and answered](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/29513/is-reinventing-the-wheel-really-all-that-bad).